# How to pass files from EC2 to S3 and S3 to EC2 using user data

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3cmd

Below code is shell script file which is created for creating New AWS EC2 instance with user data.

In this code, it creates new instance and executes cd /home and creates dirctory named with pravin.

But after that it neither downloads file from s3 nor uploads to S3.

What is wrong with that code(s3cmd get and put code).

And AMI used for this is pre-configured with AWS EC2 command line API and s3cmd.

```
str=$"#! /bin/bash"
str+=$"\ncd /home"
str+=$"\nmkdir pravin"
str+=$"\ns3cmd get inputFile.txt s3://bucketName/inputFile.txt"
str+=$\ns3cmd put resultFile.txt s3://bucketName/outputFile.txt"

echo "$str"|base64
ud=`echo -e "$str" |base64`
echo "$ud"

export JAVA_HOME=/usr
export EC2_HOME=/home/ec2-api-tools-1.6.7.1
export PATH=$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bin
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=accesskey
export AWS_SECRET_KEY=secretkey
if [ "$3" = "us-east-1" ]
then
 ec2-run-instances ami-fa791231 -t t1.micro -g groupName -n 1 -k Key1 -d "$ud" --region $3 --instance-initiated-shutdown-behavior terminate
else
    echo "Not Valid region"
fi
```

Comment: I would not share the keys with the community the way you do...:)

Comment: You should also use IAM Roles instead of passing access and secret keys (not just posting them to a public forum). See: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/06/iam-roles-for-ec2-instances-simplified-secure-access-to-aws-service-apis-from-ec2.html

Comment: Can i pass s3cmd and s3fs command as a user data to EC2 instance ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your "s3cmd get" command.  You have the parameter order backwards.  From the "s3cmd --help" output:

```
Put file into bucket
      s3cmd put FILE [FILE...] s3://BUCKET[/PREFIX]

Get file from bucket
      s3cmd get s3://BUCKET/OBJECT LOCAL_FILE
```

You can see that you need to change your get command to:

```
str+=$"\ns3cmd get s3://bucketName/inputFile.txt inputFile.txt"
```

Note that the s3:// URI comes first, before the file name.  That should fix that issue.  Your code also appears to be missing a quote for the put command:

```
str+=$"\ns3cmd put resultFile.txt s3://bucketName/outputFile.txt"
```